# How to define powerset in Data.Set.Monad?

Tags: haskell, set, monads, set-comprehension

When using [Data.Set.Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Set-Monad.html) together with `{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions}` one can define sets
almost like we did in high school, where we defined sets using comprehensions like `{x ∈ S | φ(x)}`. For example:

```
s' = [x | x <- s, phi(x)]
```

This is *not* possible using the more widely used [`Data.Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Set.html) module, as its `Set` type constructor is not a monad.

When cobbling together a toy example lately I needed the powerset `Powerset(S) = {x | x ⊆ S}` The problem is that this definition doesn't use a "generator" `x <- Y`  which is not a problem in set theory, but is required in monad comprehensions:

```
powerset s = [ x | x `isSubsetOf` s ]
```

just doesn't compile (`error: Variable not in scope: x`)

It *is* possible to convert a set to a list, take the list of all of its sublists, convert this list back to a set and then convert all of its elements to sets as well: `powerset =  (map fromList) . fromList. subsequences . toList`. But this feels like an ugly hack

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-} 
import Prelude hiding (map)
import Data.List hiding (map)
import Data.Set.Monad 

powerset :: Ord a => Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerset =  (map fromList) . fromList. subsequences . toList

oneToTen = fromList [1..10]
smallEvens = [x | x <- oneToTen, even x, x < 6] -- just like in high school!

statement = smallEvens `member` powerset oneToTen

main :: IO()
main = putStrLn $ if statement == True  then "yes" else "no"
```

... will compile and print "yes", as expected.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: `Powerset(S) = {x | x ⊆ S}` is just equivalent to `[x | x <- powerSet s]`, or thus `powerSet s`.

Comment: There is btw a `powerSet` function: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:powerSet

Comment: Yes, but `Data.Set.Set` is not a monad, and won't let me define `Set`s using monad comprehensions. (so your first example won't compile) `Data.Set.Monad.Set` _is_ a monad

Comment: it's not ugly. it's nice. just be sure to use `fromDistinctAscList` instead of `fromList`. this assuming `toList` produces ordered increasing list, which it seems it ought to. I expect the set-based code to do a lot of setifying of the interim lists, needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple recursive solution that leverages monad comprehensions:

```hs
powerset :: Ord a => Set a -> Set (Set a)
powerset s = insert s [x | elem <- s, let rest = delete elem s, x <- powerset rest]
```